# Is taking the real part required in vector orthogonality and projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

In a real inner product space, two vectors are orthogonal if $\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0$. Similarly, $$\operatorname{proj}_{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{v}) = \dfrac{\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}\rangle} \mathbf{u}.$$

My question is, are the below definitions in a complex inner product space? $$\operatorname{Re}\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle = 0 \iff\mathbf{u}\perp\mathbf{v},\qquad \qquad \operatorname{proj}_{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{v}) = \frac{\operatorname{Re}\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}\rangle} \mathbf{u}$$

Comment: Why would it not be good to define orthogonality to mean that the real part of the inner product is $0$? Because that definition would lead to $e^{i\theta}x \perp x$ for some $\theta \in [0,\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false even in one dimension. Let $V = \mathbb{C}$ as a complex vector space, $u = 1$, $v = -i$. Then $\langle u,v\rangle = 1\cdot\overline{-i} = i$, so $\text{Re}\langle u,v\rangle = 0$, yet $\langle u,v \rangle \neq 0$, i.e. $u\not\perp v$. The statement about the projection also fails for this choice of $u$ and $v$, as the projection would be zero, and in one complex dimension a zero projection is possible only if either $u$ or $v$ is zero, since any two complex numbers are complex linearly dependent.

Comment: What I meant was whether orthogonality in complex inner product spaces is defined as $\Re\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \rangle = 0$ or not.

Comment: @HenryW Thanks for clarifying your question. The answer is that it is not. The definition is the same as in real inner product spaces, $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$. Granted, what this means is not quite as geometrically evident as in real inner product spaces, but it's what we've got. The projection is defined the same way.

Comment: Wikipedia tells me that the angle between two vectors is related to $\Re (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v})$, so an angle of $0$ indicates perpendicular(orthogonal vectors). en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: That depends on a few choices; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition will tell you the angle is related not to $\text{Re}\langle u,v\rangle$, but to $|\langle u,v\rangle|$ instead. The latter appears to be the more common usage, so typically we define orthogonality by $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ if and only if $u\perp v$.